# Terraform var-file option does not work

Tags: terraform

I'm attempting to get a Terraform build to work utilizing a file for variables that I don't want in the source tree, but are required inputs.

My directory structure is pretty simple:

```
/nford   # Unix system user; echo $HOME -> /home/nford
  /deployment
    /prod
      /module_01
      variables.tf
      main.tf
      output.tf
  /secrets
    terraform.tfvars
```

All of the rest is from the `/home/nford/deployment/prod/` directory.

When I execute `terraform init` it has no complaints, saying "Terraform has been successfully initialized!"

I have tried to execute all of the following, and a lot more:

```
$ terraform validate -var-file=~/secrets/terraform.tfvars
$ terraform validate -var-file=$HOME/secrets/terraform.tfvars
$ terraform validate -var-file=/home/nford/secrets/terraform.tfvars
$ terraform plan -var-file=~/secrets/terraform.tfvars
$ terraform plan -var-file=$HOME/secrets/terraform.tfvars
$ terraform plan -var-file=/home/nford/secrets/terraform.tfvars
```

Each of these produces the same result: it displays the usage of `terraform <validate|plan>`. It gives me no other errors. It doesn't appear to run terraform at all. I have tried moving the file into the same directory and executed:

```
$ terraform validate -var-file=terraform.tfvars
$ terraform validate -var-file=./terraform.tfvars
$ terraform plan -var-file=terraform.tfvars
$ terraform plan -var-file=./terraform.tfvars
```

These produce the same result: it displays usage. I've tried dropping the `-var-file` flag altogether and it reports:

```
Error: Required variable not set: pub_key
... etc (there are a number of these)
```

`terraform plan -var "pub_key=${PUBLIC_KEY_LOC}" ...` works without any issue.

I've looked around and I can't see anyone else that has remotely this same problem: everything is around the variables not being set correctly or the like. I am not sure how to diagnose this issue, given the utter lack of useful error message. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what terraform version are you using?

Comment: I tried your scenario, and it seems to work as expected in terraform v0.11.4.  It seems that if your tfvars does not follow the right syntax you will get the usage command as output when you try to run terraform. worth checking if your tfvars file does not have any unscaped character

Comment: `$ terraform --version` returns `Terraform v0.11.7`.

Comment: @DavidPrzybilla That's a good idea... but I checked and apart from a few trailing spaces and `$HOME` there was nothing. I hard-coded the path and removed the extra characters and the same result occurred. Do you know what might need to be escaped, character-wise?

Comment: Even stripping down the file to have only `foo=bar` returns the usage.

Comment: it has to be foo="bar"

Comment: @DavidPrzybilla Ah, that did it! I think I was confused by thinking it was similar to a properties file, but the `value="key"` is pretty strict. Thanks! If you want to post an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: How do you represent a map variable in tfvars?

Comment: @flickerfly I'm not sure I understand your question or how it relates to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terraform output doesn't tell you that `terraform.tfvars` might contain incorrect syntax, instead showing the usage description. The expected syntax for a `.tfvars` file is a list of properly-escaped `name="value"` pairs, where the double quotes around the value is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes terraform files are not completely defined, for example... Let's say that you created a module with this:

```
module "example" {
   resource_name = var.resource_name
}
```

Then in your variables file you have this:

```
variable "resource_name" {
   description = "example resource name"
}

variable "resource_location" {
   description = "example resource location"
}
```

And you assign values on your .tfvars file:

```
resource_name = "resource-example-east"
```

If you haven't defined a value in your .tfvars file for "resource_location" variable then Terraform will ask you to put it manually after terraform apply, it don't cares if you are not using it.

In some cases people is using double quotes or quotes for files... the correct syntax is without quotes, please ensure that you are executing the command correctly:

```
terraform apply -var-file=myfile.tfvars
```

I hope someone finds this useful!